# Insert order of Entity Framework children

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a structure like this

```
public class Son {
  public string Name {get;set;} 
  public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class Daughter {
  public string Name {get;set;} 
  public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class Parent {
  public Daughter[] Daughters {get;set;}    
  public Son[] Sons {get;set;}
}
```

Where there is a FK Parent -> Son and Parent -> Daughter

Currently when doing a `Context.SaveChanges()` on a parent object it saves the `Parent`, and then saves the `Daughter`s and then saves the `Son`s. I need it to save the Sons before the Daughters because we have a database trigger that does validation of the Sons based on the Daughters (and will deny the whole thing if it doesnt meet a requirement)

This trigger is obviously outside the knowledge of EF.

How can I specify that Sons are dependent on Daughters in EF such that Sons get inserted first; or is there a specification or attribute that I can define insert order?

PS: Do not look too much into the contrived example (such as why we dont save it under one thing called Children). The real-world example is much more complicated but the idea of saving Sons before Daughters is there

Comment: Maybe add `public Daughter OwnerDaughter` with a `[Required]` attribute to your 'Son' class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love a challenge!

Firstly a declaration: I'm not a fan of Triggers or building a requirement for making order of insert important. My first exercise would be to exhaust all options to remove such a requirement.

After a bit of tinkering from what I can see at least when adding entities, for instance a Parent with one or more Daughters and one or more Sons, the order of insert is consistently alphabetical based on the Entity names.  For example with entities named "Parent", "Daughter", and "Son", the insert was always Parent > Daughter > Son. The order of the properties, configuration, inserts, or even the table names had no bearing on the operations, however renaming the entity class "Son" to "ASon" resulted in Sons being inserted before Daughters.  I don't know if this will carry forward to edits, but it's something to consider without getting too hacky. (Though something like this would definitely need to be documented well in the system in case someone questions a naming convention to get something inserting before something else.)

That said, getting into the hacky fun business!

Using a Son entity called ASon to force Sons before Daughters, it is possible to get EF to reverse that insert order:

```
        using (var context = new ParentDbContext())
        {
            var parent = context.Parents.Create();
            parent.Name = "Steve";

            parent.Daughters.Add(new Daughter { Name = "Elise" });
            parent.Daughters.Add(new Daughter { Name = "Susan" });
            parent.Sons.Add(new ASon { Name = "Jason" });
            parent.Sons.Add(new ASon { Name = "Duke" });
            context.Parents.Add(parent);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Out of the box this inserted Parent, Son, Son, Daughter, Daughter.

To reverse it, I overrode SaveChanges, looking for our Sons to defer saving until after everything else:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var trackedStates = new[] { EntityState.Added, EntityState.Modified };
        var trackedParentIds = ChangeTracker.Entries<Parent>().Where(x => trackedStates.Contains(x.State)).Select(x => x.Entity.ParentId).ToList();
        var addedSons = ChangeTracker.Entries<ASon>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        var modifiedSons = ChangeTracker.Entries<ASon>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        int tempid = -1;
        int modifiedParentCount = addedSons.Select(x => x.Entity.Parent.ParentId)
            .Where(x => trackedParentIds.Contains(x))
            .Count();
        List<Tuple<Parent, ASon>> associatedSons = new List<Tuple<Parent, ASon>>();
        modifiedSons.ForEach(x => { x.State = EntityState.Unchanged; });
        addedSons.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.Entity.SonId = tempid--;
            associatedSons.Add(new Tuple<Parent, ASon>(x.Entity.Parent, x.Entity));
            x.Entity.Parent.Sons.Remove(x.Entity);
            x.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        });

        var result = base.SaveChanges();

        addedSons.ForEach(x => { x.Entity.Parent = associatedSons.Single(a => a.Item2 == x.Entity).Item1; x.State = EntityState.Added; });
        modifiedSons.ForEach(x => { x.State = EntityState.Modified; });

        result += base.SaveChanges() - modifiedParentCount;
        return result;
    }
```

So what this is doing:
The first bit is easy, we find our added and modified sons. We also take a count of parents with both modified and added sons. These will get double-counted when this is done.

For modified sons, we just set their state to Unchanged.
For added sons, we need to do a bit of dirty work. We need to give them a temporary unique ID because to mark them as Unchanged, EF still wants to track their ID and when you add 2 sons it will fail here. Note that when we put them back as added, they will receive proper IDs from Identity columns, not these temporary negative ones. We also track the association of their added sons with their respective parent in a Tuple because we need to temporarily remove those sons from their parent. Finally the added son is also marked unchanged.
Now we call the base SaveChanges which will save our parents and their daughters.
For modified sons, we just need to update the state back to Modified.
For our added sons, we use our saved association to re-assign them to their parent, and then set their state back to added.
We call the base SaveChanges again, appending the affected row count to the first run, and subtract the duplicate parent references. (parents that were already counted due to being modified)

The sketchy bit is adjusting the result count for the double-save, this might not be 100% accurate but it should only be an issue if you happen to be using the result of SaveChanges. I can't say I've ever really paid much attention to that return value :)

Hopefully that gives you some ideas to play with.